# What is the performance implication of saving a component to a state?

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering what is the performance impact of saving a component to a state and if it is against good practice to do so?

Say for example I have an HOC where I am passing a callback to, and that returns a component that has all the functionality I needed, and would invoke my callback afterwards. Please see example below:

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import {
  someHOCthatReturnsAComponentClass,
  OtherComponent
} from "../some-folder";

export class A extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    ComponentInsideState: null,
    active: false
  };

  callback() {
    this.setState({ active: true });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      ComponentInsideState: someHOCthatReturnsAComponentClass(this.callback)
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { ComponentInsideState, active } = this.state;

    return (
      ComponentInsideState && (
        <ComponentInsideState>
          <OtherComponent active={active} />
        </ComponentInsideState>
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think assigning a component as state won't create any performance implications as the reference to the component is just saved as the state. But my opinion is that there is no need to set a component to state. As we can conditionally render components, i think there is no need to set a component to state.

```
{condition1 && <component1/>}
{condition2 && <component2/>}
```

or you can use ternary operator for 'if else' conditional rendering of components.

```
condition?<component1>:<component2>;
```